# asp.net gridview formatting

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has three columns date, pnl, cumpnl
I am able to add some formatting when applied to all cells using code such as

```
Protected Sub OnRowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            cell.Font.Size = 10
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Within that For...Next loop how can I reference only the cells in the pnl and cumpnl columns? I don't see anyway to reference cells by the columnheader name or index.

Update:

by Using a RowDataBound event I can now reset the format of the values in the columns but the setting of the forecolor based on the cells value keeps erring ("Input string not in correct format"). Also, I am hardcoding the the column indexes. I need a way to dynamically get the column index based on the column header name

```
Protected Sub gvDataRetrieval_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDataRetrieval.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To 2
            e.Row.Cells(i).Text = FormatCurrency(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, 2).ToString()
            If Double.Parse(e.Row.Cells(i).Text) < 0 Then e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside for each loop:

```
e.Row.Cells(index)
```

Eg.
For adding header tooltip:

```
    Protected Sub Grid1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridRowEventArgs)
       //setting row cells
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      For i As Integer = 1 To e.Row.Cells.Count
        If i = 1 Then
           e.Row.Cells(i).Font.Size= 8
        ELSE
           e.Row.Cells(i).Font.Size= 12
        END IF
      NEXT
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: of course i can hard code the references to those columns but i want to dynamically be able to test for a column header (and retrieve it's index) and format those columns appropriately

Comment: You can add template column to your grid & the do :e.Row.FindControl("IDofyourcontrol")

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear, I want to be able to iterate through each cell in a datarow, and only change the formatting dependent on which column the cell is in. To do that i need a way to test for what column the cell is in during the iteration. something like If cell.column("pnl") then ForeColor= Color.Red

Answer (score 0):

Kapil's code in C#

```
        private void DataGrid1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1) { e.Row.Cells[i-1].Font.Bold = true; } else { e.Row.Cells[i-1].Font.Bold = false; }
            }
        }
    }
```